# php how to add array to array unlimit

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a button, when user click `add button` I used `JavaScript` and `Ajax` send data to `php` for add to `array` for store in `session`.

here is my code `JavaScript`

```
     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                }
     };
    xhttp.open("GET","/ajax_addItem.php?id="+id+"&name="+name+"&price="+price+"&task=storeSession", true);
    xhttp.send();
```

And this is `PHP`

```
     $id = $_GET['id'];
     $name = $_GET['name'];
     $price = $_GET['price'];
     $_SESSION['name']= array("id"=>$id,"name"=>$name,"price"=>$price);
```

My problem related to `PHP`,My code is data always replace news data when I click `add button`.How I can add all to `$_SESION['name']` as `Array in Array` or `Array list`?

Comment: To who up vote,I don't understand, why just I post question and have up vote?

Comment: You need to update your `$_SESSION['name']` array into `$_SESSION['name'][]`. Why you need to update is because whenever you push the newest data it replaces the last one and store the newest one. [Check This](https://3v4l.org/GnMLH)

Comment: `$_SESSION['lastpostedstuff'] = $_POST;`

Comment: it's work, all ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want `$_SESSION['name']` to be an array of arrays, create `$_SESSION['name']` as an array first, and use the bracket notation `[]` to push new arrays into it, i.e.:

```php
// Create new array if it doesn't exist
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    $_SESSION['name'] = array();
}

// Retrieve request parameters
$id = $_GET['id'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
$price = $_GET['price'];

// Push new array
$_SESSION['name'][] = array(
    "id" => $id,
    "name" => $name,
    "price" => $price
    );
```